# Laravel проблема 500 http error

Tags: laravel, http, hosting

Доброго времени суток. Пытаюсь залить Laravel (5.4) проект на хостинг. В итоге получаю 500 HTTP Error.
Проверял уже все что возможно. С правами точно проблем нет, даже при 777 НА ВСЕ выдает тот же 500. Логи молчат, доступа к apache log нету, и доступ даже не собираются давать (саппорт молчит). Уже не знаю что делать. На локалхосте все работает. Подскажите может кто сталкивался. Хоть скажите куда копать. Спасибо заранее.

Comment: Меняйте хостера на вменяемого.

Answer (score 2):

у меня на одном из хостингов была проблема с `mod_negotiation`
в `.htacces`, проблему решило удаление секции:

```
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>
```

После этого заработало